# Problem with forcing SSL using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl

I have the following .htaccess file:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from XX.XXX.XXX.XXX

RewriteEngine  on
RewriteBase    /

RewriteCond    %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond    %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule    . /index.php

RewriteCond    %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule    ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Which is supposed to:

- Only allow access from my IP (numbers changed to Xs to protect the innocent)
- Send any request which is not a specific file through to /index.php
- Force https for the entire domain

As far as I can see, it's identical to a previous project, which was admittedly on a different hosting provider, but that worked like a charm. This time it's resulting in a message saying "*Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.*".

Anybody know what's going on & what I need to change please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps your new hosting provider is using some sort of setup (like a reverse proxy) that's preventing the HTTPS variable from being set. You may be able to use something else (like SERVER_PORT, or perhaps a header set by the remote proxy, assuming there is one) to determine if the request is HTTPS or HTTP.

Comment: Thanks Laurence, I didn't think it was my code. I think I might need to find another solution as you suggest.